# Vaadin, change grid column color

Tags: css, grid, themes, vaadin, vaadin7

I want to change the column color of my grid. Unfortunately nothing happens... here is my code:

```
grid.setCellStyleGenerator(( Grid.CellReference cellReference ) -> {
            if ( "name".equals( cellReference.getPropertyId() ) ) {
                return "highlight-green";
            } else {
                return "rightAligned";
            } 
        });
```

**mytheme.scss:**

```
@import "../valo/valo.scss";

@mixin mytheme {
  @include valo;

  // Insert your own theme rules here

  .rightAligned {
      text-align: right;
  }

 .v-table-row.v-table-row-highlight-green,
 .v-table-row-odd.v-table-row-highlight-green {
      background-color: #00ff00;
  }
}
```

The `rightAligned` works great, but `highlight-green` doesn't

Comment: Firefox does a great job for [inspecting CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Examine_and_edit_CSS) style issues. You can use the built in developer tool to check why your style is overwritten (if so) and even add/change styles at client side for testing.

Comment: `v-table-row` and `v-table-row-odd` is for Vaadin Table, the Grid component uses other style classes `v-grid-row` and `v-grid-row-stripe`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `background-color: #00ff00 !important;`

It looks like you need to rewrite existing styles of your framework, `!important` must help with this.

Comment: When I am adding styles to my theme, the `!important` is not required. The precedence is controlled by `@include` valo theme in the beginning of the `@mixin`.

Comment: Can you create jsfiddle please? So it will be easier to find solution for your case.

Comment: Lets wait for feedback from OP.

Comment: `!important` doesn't change anything on my side.